# Can she go in or not?

Tags: word, story, situation

I overheard this conversation from a couple sitting at the next table in a lunch restaurant.

> "That was wrong, Bernie?"
>
> "Yes. You cannot ---(INAUDIBLE) -in the kitchen Mary."
>
> "What if I ----- (inaudible)"
>
> "No Honey, you cannot ---- in the kitchen either. You are not allowed in the kitchen, Mary."
>
> "That’s irrational Bernie"
>
> "That’s the way it is Mary"

Two minutes later I heard:

> Mary : You know the Smiths are coming for dinner tonight.
>
> Bernie: O that’s right. Need any ---?
>
> Mary: You take care of ___. I will take care of the cooking.
>
> Bernie: That’s a lot of work
>
> Mary: That’s ok. I like cooking. I will be in the kitchen all afternoon.
>
> Bernie: Enjoy

**HINT**

> The first part of the conversation may relate to a game.

**Can you fill the blanks and explain this conversation?**

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a puzzle so much as it is a game of Mad Libs.

Comment: Are you going to provide the answer even if it is closed?

Comment: ForguesR  Please Google Pickleball and Kitchen rule

Answer (score 7):

Quite straight forward really...

> They are having a conversation in the first part about the kitchen in the restaurant and the wife want's to do, or have something, done in the kitchen there (at the restaurant) and her husband is telling her that it can't be done and that she cannot do it there (at the restaurant).

And in the second part of the conversation:

> The wife mentions that friends are coming over to the house and a conversation begins about what will happen in the kitchen at HOME.

Comment: My answer is quite different. This is interesting

Answer (score 4):

Unlikely, perhaps, but I'm assuming Mary isn't much of a gardener:

> You cannot *plant deadly nightshade* in the kitchen Mary
> What if I  *had a yew tree*
> No Honey you cannot *grow other poisonous/toxic plants* in the kitchen either. Yew are not allowed in the kitchen, Mary.

Perhaps more likely, based on Mary's name:

> You cannot *keep the goat* in the kitchen Mary
> What if I *let in my little lamb*
> No Honey you cannot *keep a sheep* in the kitchen either. Ewe are not allowed in the kitchen, Mary.
> Later: You take care of *the animals*. I will take care of the cooking

Comment: How awful of y~~`|x. o9Sgob  @~]| xx    NO CARRIER

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty confident with my answer...

First part :

> They are playing Clue at the restaurant!
> The blanks are aprobably : "stay", "suggest", "suggest".

Second part :

> They are just planing the evening so Mary is allowed to stay all the afternoon in the *real* kitchen.
> The blanks are probably : "help", "the cleaning".

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps,

> Mary is a chef/ one aspiring to be

and, the blanks of the first conversation can be

> Advice /suggest the chef of the restaurant, experiment, enter

and the blanks of the second conversation can be

> Help/assistance, drinks

respectively.

Comment: This appears, if I've understood your intent correctly, to be the same as Dr t's answer which was posted 7 hours earlier. Before posting an answer, please look to see what's already there and whether your answer adds anything to the existing answers.